# Knapsack algorithm with proper ratio constraint and weight constraint

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Problem:
You're a juice maker looking for the best suppliers for your business. The suppliers are selling concentrates that have 3 ingredients: X:Y:Z in different proportions. Your juice needs to have these proportions as 1:1:1, otherwise it won't be tasty. The weight of the concentrate is the sum of its ingredients in lbs and all the suppliers are selling their concentrates for the same price, however your truck can only carry up to 400 pounds of concentrates. 
Find the best suppliers for your business: buy (find) as many pounds of concentrate as you can (but less than 400lbs), knowing that the ratio of ingredients other than 1:1:1 won't be acceptable.

Input:
The first line tells you how many concentrates are sold on the market (less than 200)
The next n lines are about the proportions of the X:Y:Z ingredients of concentrates (in pounds)

Output:
First line should be the sum of weight of the ingredients of concentrates you'll be buying (smaller than 400 lbs)
The second line should tell how many concentrates you've got to buy to get this amount keeping the proper proportions

Example:

```
in:
4 //how many concentrates are sold on the market
1 2 3 //first concentrate contains 1lb of X, 2lbs of Y, 3 lbs of Z
0 4 1
1 3 4
1 1 1
2 1 0

out: 
12 //4lbs of ingredient X + 4lbs Y + 4lbs Z
3 //we're buying three concentrates: the first one, fourth and fifth (1 2 3; 1 1 1; 2 1 0) so we're getting the biggest amount of it with 1:1:1 ratio of ingredients
```

My solution:
My solution was a brute-force method that's very slow when there are a lot of suppliers as its complexity is 2^(n-2) - this algorithm would just create all possible combinations of the concentrates we could buy and it would check if their proportions are 1:1:1, if yes then it would compare them and find the one with the highest amount of total ingredients totaling less than 400lbs.

I'm looking for a dynamic-approach algorithm, however, I have no idea how to do it with the proper ratio constraint.

Comment: What if there is more than one combination that works?

Comment: Do you mean that there are two or more combinations of proper proportions and the weight of the sum of its ingredients is the same? The problem doesn't say anything about it, so I'm assuming that there will be only one combination like this. But yes, there will be more than one combinations that are in proper ratio, but we're looking for the one that will have the biggest amount of ingredients possible (and all ingredients are 1:1:1).

Comment: It's quite likely that there will be multiple combinations that result in the best weight, so you do need to know whether to maximize or minimize the second line of the answer.

Comment: Correct, if that is possible (there is more than one combination with the same total best weight and proper 1:1:1 ratio of ingredients), then we should minimize the second line (so we're only buying smaller amount of concentrates instead of paying more for the same amount of ingredients). I'm sorry, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`400/3 = 133` which means that the answer can have no more than 133 lbs of any ingredient.  So the DP array is `array[134][134][134]`, where each entry in the array is the number-of-concentrates-to-buy to achieve that combination.

That array has about 2.4 million entries in it, and the array needs to be scanned once for each input (less than 200). So you're looking at about 500 million operations to fill in the array. That's reasonable on a modern computer.

After the array is filled, a simple scan finds the answer

```
for ( i = 133; i > 0; i-- )
    if ( array[i][i][i] > 0 )
        the answer is array[i][i][i]
```

Comment: Just to confirm: so for example if array[1][1][1] == 1, then it means that there's one combination where the sum is 3 and there's one ingredient X, one Y, one Z? And for array[133][133][133] == 1, there's one combination with sum of 400 and 133Xes, 133Ys, 133Zs? And we're iterating the array from the end, so it can just stop after it finds its first answer?

Comment: @drakerc Yes, that's the idea. And for example, if `array[40][29][31]` is 7, that means that you can buy 7 items that contain 40X, 29Y, and 31Z. If the next item is 2X,4Y,3Z then another reachable combination is `array[42][33][34] = 8`. But, If you already had `array[42][33][34] == 6`, then you can ignore the new combination, because you're trying to minimize the answer. After the array is completely filled in, the only array entries you care about are the entries on the diagonal where `X == Y == Z`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll think about implementing the algorithm to fill the array properly and I'll let you know if there'll be any additional problems.

Comment: just to let you know, this method works perfectly, for the biggest array possible (with 400 ingredients), it takes my PC about 30 seconds to find the output. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that might allow us a lower operational complexity than user3386109's great idea. Conduct the sums enumeration separately for each member of the triple, and trace a match for (index,cardinality) for combinations across the three enumerations: for each member of the triples, `x`, `y`, and `z` in `(x,y,z)` iterate over a separate one dimensional array representing sums up to 133, indexing cardinality:

```
# for example, Xs enumeration only
for index, (x,y,z) in triples:
  for s in [133 - x ... 0]
    if sums_x[s].cardinalities.length > 0:
      for cardinality in sums_x[s].cardinalities:
        sums_x[s + x].by_index.add( (index,cardinality + 1) ) # this is a set of (index,cardinality) tuples
        sums_x[s + x].cardinalities["cardinality + 1"].push( index ) # hash cardinality to indexes

  sums_x[x].by_index.add( (index,1) )
  sums_x[x].cardinalities["1"].push( index )
```

Once we've iterated over the three one-dimensional arrays, one for each member of the triples, we can trace possible matches. These are made rare by the low probability of tracing a consistent match of (sum,cardinality,index) across all three enumerations.

For example:

```
(1 2 3),(0 4 1),(1 3 4),(1 1 1),(2 1 0)

index = 0
sums_x[1].by_index = {(0,1)} # (index,cardinality)
sums_x[1].cardinalities = {"1": [0]} # cardinality: indexes

index = 1
sums_x[0].by_index = {(1,1)} # (index,cardinality)
sums_x[0].cardinalities = {"0,1": [1]} # cardinality: indexes
sums_x[1].by_index = {(0,1), (1,2)}
sums_x[1].cardinalities = {"1": [0], "2": [1]}

...

index = 4
sums_x[4].by_index = {(4,3), (4,4)} # (index,cardinality)
sums_x[4].cardinalities = {"2": [3], "3": [4], "4": [4]} # cardinality: indexes

sums_y[4].by_index = {(1,1), (3,2), (4,2), (4,3)}
sums_y[4].cardinalities = {"1": [1], "2": [3,4], "3": [4]}

sums_z[4].by_index = {(1,2), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (4,2)}
sums_z[4].cardinalities = {"2": [1,3,4], "1": [2], "3": [4]}
```

As we can see, for the sum 4 in this example, there is only one match of (index,cardinality) across all three sum structures, (4,3), which we can then trace back using the associated values:

```
sums_z[4]: 4,3 
  => val 0 => lookup by z sum (4 - 0) and cardinality (3 - 1) 
  => sums_z[4].cardinalities[2] yields only one match across: index 3
  => lookup by z sum (4 - 1) and cardinality (2 - 1)
  => sums_z[3].cardinalities[1] yields a match across: index 0
  => possible solution, indexes [4,3,0]
```